# How to "patch" a Document in DocumentDB using Mongo commands

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-documentdb

My code is below:

```
MyModel requestID = new MyModel
            {
                "id" = "123"
            };

MyModel toUpdate = new MyModel
            {
               "is_cancelled" : true
            };

FilterDefinition<MyModel> filter = requestID.ToBsonDocument();
UpdateDefinition<MyModel> update = toUpdate.ToBsonDocument();
collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

My 1 Document in DocumentDB for example is:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "delnum": "100001"
}
```

My toUpdate is:

```
{
  "is_cancelled" : true
}
```

My expected document after FindOneAndUpdate is:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "delnum": "100001",
  "is_cancelled" : true
}
```

but what is happening is, it is replacing my document with id=123 to below:

```
{
  "is_cancelled" : true
}
```

I would like to know if I am doing it wrong, or what my expectation outcome is not correct.

---

Edited Code:

```
MyModel requestID = new MyModel
            {
                "id" = "123"
            };

MyModel toUpdate = new MyModel
            {
               "is_cancelled" : true
            };

var builder = Builders<MyModel>.Update;
UpdateDefinition<MyModel> update =null;

toUpdate.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(
                    x => update = builder.Set(x.Name, x.GetValue(toUpdate, null))

FilterDefinition<MyModel> filter = requestID.ToBsonDocument();

if (update == null) return;


collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

EDIT:
code below what worked for me.

```
var filterData = Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Eq("id", "123"); //requestID
var updateData = new BsonDocumentUpdateDefinition<MyModel>(new BsonDocument("$set", toUpdate)); 
await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, updateData , new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<MyModel>() { IsUpsert = false });
```

Comment: Could you provide the implementation for *toUpdate*?

Comment: hi @vladimir, thanks for your response. I modified my post to include the toUpdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying what you want to update.

Mongo expects json to look like this:

```
{
  "$set" : {
    "is_cancelled" : true
  }
}
```

You can use the update builder to make that easier:

```
var builder = Builders<MyModel>.Update;
var update = builder.Set("is_cancelled", true);
```

You can also chain multiple `Set` methods on the builder:

```
var update = builder.Set("a", 1).Set("b", 2);
```

Comment: i see.. I want to avoid loop on the toUpdate to do a build. i think I will have to just append that $set instead.

Comment: What do you mean by loop?

Comment: in some cases, the body being passed to us has multiple fields: is_cancelled, is_delivered, etc..

Comment: @Sid Updated answer to show how to update multiple fields at once. Note that you're not limited to just `Set`, you can also use `Inc` etc

Comment: Hi. I added an "Edited Code" above.. I cannot use a hardcoded string because the update is passed by the "toUpdate" as parameter. I wanted to only update/patch the fields that are not null in the toUpdate parameter. I set my model to json ignore nulls.

Comment: if I changed the update to  update.ToBsonDocument() .. it is currently removing my document instead of updating it.